# Confused about when update rails version from 5.0.2 to n 6.0.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to update an app from 5.0.2 to 6.0.2.1 using my own gem and jsonb_accessor gem.
So my gem which uses ActiveRecord, my gem will need to use ActiveRecord >= 6.0.

Then, I update my gemfile in my app (not in my own gem) with

> gem 'rails', '6.0.2.1'

I don't know what to do with this message when running `bundle install`, I also tried to run `bundle update`

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activerecord (= 5.0.2)

  In Gemfile:
    jsonb_accessor was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 5.0)

    networkcore (= 0.0.4) was resolved to 0.0.4, which depends on
      activerecord (~> 6.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Here is the gemspec from my own gem

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'networkcore'
  s.version     = '0.0.4'
  s.date        = '2020-01-17'
  s.summary     = "SUMMARY"
  s.description = "DESCRIPTION"
  s.authors     = ["AUTHOR"]
  s.files       = ["lib/networkcore.rb"]
  s.license       = 'MIT'
  s.add_dependency "activerecord", '~> 6.0'
end
```

Do you any advice or ideas ?

> ruby '2.5.1'

Comment: Why do you require 6.0 in your own gem? Just relax your requirement.If you built it, you can fix it.

Comment: You are fixing the gem version and apparently the version you are fixing is not compatible. You should relax your version by adding ~> or >= to a minimum requirement if you are aware of the versions. I guess you should not specify the version if you are not sure. That way you will get the latest possible.

Comment: When your gem really requires Rails `~> 6.0` and doesn't work with Rails `5.0` anymore then you need to update Rails to at least `6.0.0` too. Is that an option? Did you try that? Otherwise is relaxing the requirements for your gem to Rails `>= 5.0` an option?

Comment: @Casper I need to update my app to rails version at least 6 in order to to use ActiveStorage.

Comment: Please copypaste your Gemfile into the question also. Let's see what you have in it.

Answer (score 0):

change your gemspec file to read like this:

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'networkcore'
  s.version     = '0.0.4'
  s.date        = '2020-01-17'
  s.summary     = "SUMMARY"
  s.description = "DESCRIPTION"
  s.authors     = ["AUTHOR"]
  s.files       = ["lib/networkcore.rb"]
  s.license       = 'MIT'
  s.add_dependency "activerecord", '>= 5.0'
end
```

That will tell bundler that any version of active record equal to or greater than 5.0 is acceptable. Since your version is 5.0.2 it will satisfy the requirement.